# Fatal error: Class 'SMTP' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\global\class.phpmailer.php on line 1235

Tags: php, sql

> Fatal error: Class 'SMTP' not found in 
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\global\class.phpmailer.php on line 1235

My code which the above error code points to (line 1235):

```
   public function getSMTPInstance()
    {
        if (!is_object($this->smtp)) {
            $this->smtp = new SMTP;
        }
        return $this->smtp;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is as a result of you using the new version of PHP Mailer.
This new ver requires 
`require_once 'inc/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';`
before you can instantiate mail function
`$mail = new PHPMailer();`
so do changes where necessary, stop using
`require_once 'inc/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php';`

Comment: He may not have loaded the classes properly, but this is **not** caused by the version of PHP!

Comment: Now is more accurate, but still "wrong", you can still manually load all the classes used by PHPmailer, but if you don't then you obviously get the error.

Comment: @MatteoTassinari You are correct... I just figured that out in my project